# Is this small-signal gain correct?

Tags: mosfet

All MOSFETs (not JFETS)

**Have I calculated the small-signal gain correctly?**
[image]

IGNORE body effect etc. but not channel length modulation

I was basically able to get rid of M2 apart from its resistance.

Comment: Quick analysis in my head: if \$r_{o1}, r_{o2}, r_{o3}\$ are infinitely high impedances I expect the gain to be \$-g_{m1} / g_{m3}\$. Your formula has an extra "1 +" in the denominator which I do not expect.Since the \$r_o\$ only make the gain lower I do not expect their values to be present in the numerator. Also: **draw** the small signal equivalent circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is common source amplifier for which the gain is given by \$-g_{1} * Resistance_{seen by the small signal VCCS }\$
The small signal resistance seen by the small signal VCVS of \$M_{1}\$ is \$r_{o1}||r_{o2}||r_{o3}||\frac{1}{g_{3}}\$
So the small signal gain of the system is \$-g_{1}(r_{o1}||r_{o2}||r_{o3}||\frac{1}{g_{3}})\$
And for sanity check \$r_{o1}=r_{o2}=r_{o3}=infinity\$ the gain is equal to \$\frac{-g_{1}}{g_{3}}\$